# Is the launch web_url in the manifest ever used for a Google Apps Marketplace app?

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

A Google Apps Marketplace app is now published via the Chrome Web Store.  You can specify a URL as part of the Marketplace SDK (universal navigation) and as a launch web_url in the Chrome store manifest.

For a Marketplace app with universal navigation URL provided, is the launch web_url (in the manifest) ever used?